# Redirect using AngularJS MVC4

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Already done research and looked up doc. How can I use AngularJS to go from page1 to page2

Module  **(I'm not sure am I suppose to put in Index.cshtml)**

```
    var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'Anj.FormController'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
      when("/home",
        {  templateUrl: "/Index.cshtml" }).
      when("/form",
        { templateUrl: "/Form" }).
      otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Form.csthml" });
});
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="FormCtrl"> <a href="#/form">Go to Form</a>.</div>
```

Form.cshtml

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="FormCtrl"><a href="#/home">Go to Home</a>.</div>
```

**I don't think put anything in the controller, if yes please tell me or show me the code. thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your templateUrl to "/[ControllerName]/Index"

Where [ControllerName] is controller that you going to call

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'Anj.FormController'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
      when("/home",
        {  templateUrl: "/Home/Index" }).
      when("/form",
        { templateUrl: "/Form" }).
      otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Home/Form" });
});
```

Comment: Nope , dosen't like me at all